# Winforms Localization bug

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

I've creted a simple winforms application with only one label. On the default localization language it was set like this
`label1.Visible = False`

I've changed the language to German (or any other language for that matter) and set `label1.Visible = True`

After saving and compiling, the label's visibility changed back to False (On the properties form) and I've seen that the German resx file doesn't save the label1.Visible property

I guess that it wasn't saved in the resx file because 'Visible=True' is the default value for labels, but when I run the application on German localization it takes the value 'Visible=False' from the default localization.

It there a way to do this? because it seems like a bug and i can't find a way to overcome it.
I've tried saving this property in the German resx manually but it gets overriden whenever i compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is to hide the label in the default localization by setting AutoSize = False and Size = (0, 0)